# Is there a word for an election candidate who does not want anyone to do the job?

Tags: single-word-requests, politics

There are terms for election candidates who have no intention of winning. These include paper candidates, fielded to allow people to show support for a point of view, but where the candidate does not expect, or wish, to win. Another is dummy candidate where the candidate hopes to attract votes away from one of the major candidates in order to benefit the other. There are also stalking horse candidates aiming to show support for change, and so encourge bigger beasts to enter the fray.

I am looking for a term for a candidate who does want to win the election, but has no intention of fulfilling the role if elected. He wishes to be elected in order to prevent it being done at all. Is there a word or phrase with this meaning?

Here is an example. An elected official is responsible for arranging for public footpaths to be kept clear of weeds and obstacles and in a usable condition. Many of these paths run adjacent to people's back gardens or across farmland. The current holder of the post is a keen rambler and walker and has been doing a particularly good job, and the paths are better used. However many of the local residents would prefer the paths to be less used and somebody is standing for the post who intends to do the very minimum he can get away with, becasue he, like many of his neighbours, does not want the paths to be maintained.

A similar thing happens in the UK Parliament where political party Sinn Fein have seven MPs who refuse to take their seats. This is entirely legal and they were quite open about their intent before the election.

Comment: Sounds like your "paper candidate".

Comment: @alwayslearning - no, a paper candidate does not want to win but wants to get votes to show how people feel. I am looking for someone who does want (and reasonably hope) to win but is quite open that if elected he will refuse to do the duties of his post.

Comment: It is unclear how such a candidate would 'prevent it being done at all'. If he doesn't want to actually hold the office, then at some point after winning the election, he will have to resign, and that will normally trigger some procedure for finding a replacement.

Comment: @jsw29 thank you, and sorry it is unclear. It is sometimes possible to hold an office without actually performing the duties of the office. I am thinking af a case where the candidate intends to hold the office but just not fulfil the responsbilities. In many cases there might be processes to force such a person to resign, but sometimes there aren't.  There are UK members of Parliament who never attend Parliament, for example. This is not quitethe scenario I have in mind. I will amend my question. Thank you.

Comment: If the majority of the constituents actually wish that the paths not be maintained, and they expressed that wish by voting for this official, then it seems that, by ensuring that the paths are not maintained, he **is** fulfilling the duties of his office.

Comment: @jsw29  Good point. The difficulty is that the paths are supposed to be maintained for the benefit of the wider community including those from elsewhere who merely walk through the parish. The county requires every parish to elect an official to maintain the footpaths in its area, but the local residents who actually elect the official don't want them maintained. If you say the first duty of an official is to follow the wishes of his electorate,then I suppose he is fulfilling his role, but he is not fulfilling it according to its definition.